# Issues with updating a python dictionary in a while loop

Tags: python

so I am new to python and having some issues with updating a dictionary using a while loop. For some reason, the code iterates through the index i before the update call, so it only updates the final items in the lists used as the parameters. For instance, the length of names is 34, so it will only add the 34th item from each list. The code looks like this:

```
def hurricane_data_entry(names, months, years, max_sustainted_winds, areas_affected, damages, deaths):
    hurricane_dictionary = {}
    i = 0
    while i < len(names):
        hurricane_dictionary.update({'Name': names[i], 'Month': months[i], 'Year': years[i], 'Max Sustained Wind': max_sustained_winds[i], 'Areas Affected': areas_affected[i], 'Damages': damages[i], 'Deaths': deaths[i]})
        i += 1
    return hurricane_dictionary
```

Comment: it's not clear what your intended final outcome is. Dictionaries by definition can only have *one* value for each key, so each iteration of the loop is simply overwriting the old values - so it's 100% expected that you end up with just the last values in `names` in the dictionary.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I see the issue. Its trying to assign it to one entry, rather than separate entries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you try to generate a series of dicts for each name.
You could use a generator like:

```
def hurricane_data_entry(
        names: list,
        months: list,
        years: list,
        max_sustained_winds: list,
        areas_affected: list,
        damages: list,
        deaths: list,
        *,
        missing='N/A'
):
    """
    Generator yielding a dictionary for each name,
    where the other keys will be populated if the list it gets populated from
    is as long as the list of names
    """
    for name in names:
        yield {
            'Name': name,
            'Month': next(months, missing),
            'Year': next(years, missing),
            'Max Sustained Wind': next(max_sustained_winds, missing),
            'Areas Affected': next(areas_affected, missing),
            'Damages': next(damages, missing),
            'Deaths': next(deaths, missing),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating the values in the dictionary instead of adding the keys too.
For example, you can update your dictionary like this:

```
hurricane_dictionary.update({'Name'+str(i): names[i], 'Month'+str(i): months[i], 'Year'+str(i): years[i], 'Max Sustained Wind'+str(i): max_sustained_winds[i], 'Areas Affected'+str(i): areas_affected[i], 'Damages'+str(i): damages[i], 'Deaths'+str(i): deaths[i]})
```

Comment: Well, that is useful to know. I am still very new to python, and have not seen that yet. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a list of dicts or a dict of dicts.
You should use a for loop and `enumerate()`.

```py
def hurricane_data_entry(names, months, years, max_sustainted_winds, areas_affected, damages, deaths):
    hurricane_dictionary = {}
    hurricane_list = []
    i = 0
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        hurricane_dictionary[name] = {'Name': names[i], 'Month': months[i], 'Year': years[i], 'Max Sustained Wind': max_sustained_winds[i], 'Areas Affected': areas_affected[i], 'Damages': damages[i], 'Deaths': deaths[i]}
        hurricane_list.append({'Name': names[i], 'Month': months[i], 'Year': years[i], 'Max Sustained Wind': max_sustained_winds[i], 'Areas Affected': areas_affected[i], 'Damages': damages[i], 'Deaths': deaths[i]})
    return hurricane_dictionary, hurricane_list
```

A dict of dicts has the clear advantage that you can get a dict for each hurricane with `hurricane_dictionary['Katrina']` while the list is just a list. To get a specific entry you need to now its index (e. g. `hurricane_list[23]`).